# Confusion about the notation of empty interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Currently, I'm studying about intervals. I got the basic understanding and knowledge about them but while reading the page about intervals in Wikipedia, under the ***classification of intervals*** tab, I didn't understand some of the notations used for the **empty interval**. They are

$(b,a)$

$(b,a]$

$[b,a)$

*where  $b>a$*

What does the upper-bound (b) written before the lower-bound (a) in these three notations mean? And how do these notations work?

Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Because $(b,a) = \{ r \in \mathbb R \mid x < a < b <x \}$.

Comment: See also the post [Why is the empty set considered an interval?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228307/why-is-the-empty-set-considered-an-interval)

Comment: Yes, I've seen it but why's there nothing after the $≤$ in (A,≤) in the first line ?

Comment: $(A, \le)$ is not an "interval"... It is the "environment"; in calculus it is $\mathbb R$ with the usual ordering $\le$ between *real* numbers. An *interval* $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! **_the domain is a set of real numbers that contains a non-empty open interval_** could you please tell me what the highlighted line means? This is the last thing I'd like to know.

Comment: Obviously, a **non-empty interval** means that the said interval cannot be a "degenerate" one, like $(a,a)$ and $(b,a)$ with $b > a$, because in these cases the  inetrvals are empty.

Comment: and does **open** have any significance over here?

Comment: See [Interval (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) : **open** $(a,b)$; **closed** $[a,b]$.

Comment: Got it... Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *empty interval* is obviously ... empty; it is an empty set of numbers.

Why e.g. $(b,a) = \emptyset$ when $b > a$ ?

Because, in general :

> $(a,b) = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid a < x \text { and } x < b \}$.

When $b > a$ we have that :

> > $(b,a) = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid b < x \text { and } x < a \}$

and there are no $x$ that satisfies the condition.