# Empty interval or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Looking for my problem I've found an answer about completely empty interval:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228313 that's clear.

But what about this thing: [0,0) or [x,x) - an inclusive beginning and an exclusive end?
Does it make x a part of this interval, or does the "exclusiveness" take it out? What is then taken as "higher", inclusiveness or exclusiveness? Does it make sense whatsoever?

Comment: $[a,b)=\{x\in \mathbb R\mid x\geq a\text{ and }x<b\}$. Therefore $[0,0)=\varnothing $ since there are no element s.t. $x\geq  0$ and $x<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an empty interval, not even a point.
for an interval (a,b) or [a,b) or (a,b], b>a should be required.
but for [a,a], it could be considered as a point with no length.